# WordPress Custom Taxonomy - Oops! That page can’t be found- Error 404

Tags: wordpress, taxonomy, custom-taxonomy

I installed a new WP site, no plugins just a fresh site.
I need to create a custom taxonomy with the name Studios.
I put the code in function.php. then I went to the permalinks and saved.
When I go to link mysite.com/studios I get his error -> Oops! That page can’t be found. Error 404
I tried to uninstall WP. But nothing, same error. I don't understand if the code is wrong or what is wrong.
I got this code from (https://metabox.io/taxonomy-generator/)

```
add_action( 'init', 'your_prefix_register_taxonomy' );
function your_prefix_register_taxonomy() {
    $args = [
        'label'  => esc_html__( 'Studios', 'your-textdomain' ),
        'labels' => [
            'menu_name'                  => esc_html__( 'Studios', 'your-textdomain' ),
            'all_items'                  => esc_html__( 'All Studios', 'your-textdomain' ),
            'edit_item'                  => esc_html__( 'Edit Studio', 'your-textdomain' ),
            'view_item'                  => esc_html__( 'View Studio', 'your-textdomain' ),
            'update_item'                => esc_html__( 'Update Studio', 'your-textdomain' ),
            'add_new_item'               => esc_html__( 'Add new Studio', 'your-textdomain' ),
            'new_item'                   => esc_html__( 'New Studio', 'your-textdomain' ),
            'parent_item'                => esc_html__( 'Parent Studio', 'your-textdomain' ),
            'parent_item_colon'          => esc_html__( 'Parent Studio', 'your-textdomain' ),
            'search_items'               => esc_html__( 'Search Studios', 'your-textdomain' ),
            'popular_items'              => esc_html__( 'Popular Studios', 'your-textdomain' ),
            'separate_items_with_commas' => esc_html__( 'Separate Studios with commas', 'your-textdomain' ),
            'add_or_remove_items'        => esc_html__( 'Add or remove Studios', 'your-textdomain' ),
            'choose_from_most_used'      => esc_html__( 'Choose most used Studios', 'your-textdomain' ),
            'not_found'                  => esc_html__( 'No Studios found', 'your-textdomain' ),
            'name'                       => esc_html__( 'Studios', 'your-textdomain' ),
            'singular_name'              => esc_html__( 'Studio', 'your-textdomain' ),
        ],
        'public'               => true,
        'show_ui'              => true,
        'show_in_menu'         => true,
        'show_in_nav_menus'    => true,
        'show_tagcloud'        => true,
        'show_in_quick_edit'   => true,
        'show_admin_column'    => false,
        'show_in_rest'         => true,
        'hierarchical'         => false,
        'query_var'            => true,
        'sort'                 => false,
        'rewrite_no_front'     => false,
        'rewrite_hierarchical' => false,
        'rewrite' => true
    ];
    register_taxonomy( 'studio', [ 'post' ], $args );
}
```

Answer (score 0):

You have created a custom taxonomy, so your URL(mysite.com/studios) not working, if want to use this URL then create a custom post type.

Comment: Thanks for the info, I managed to create a page and use a plugin shortcode, to create a specific page taxonomy.